# c++ use random access file with class that include a vector

Tags: c++, class, serialization, vector, randomaccessfile

I want to create some object from a class that include a `vector<int>` and I want to save that object in a file and read from that file another time, but the program does not read the class data correctly in a new object of that class.

For example, it can read size of my vector (that is 500) but it cannot read the value of the vector's cell! Sometimes the program will terminate and print nothing, when my file include couple of objects or more.

```
class my_class {
    int counter;
    vector<int> v;
public:
    my_class():counter(0),v(500,0){}
    void fill_vec(int x) {
        v.at(counter++)=x;
    }

    const vector<int> & get_vec () const {
        return v;
    }

    const my_class & operator=(const my_class &inp){
        v=inp.v;
        counter=inp.counter;
    return *this;
    }
};


void write_to_file(my_class x) {
    fstream opf("/home/rzz/file/my_file.dat", ios::in |ios::out|ios::binary); // my file has been created before - no problem to creat file here
    opf.seekp(0,ios::end);
    opf.write(reinterpret_cast < char *> (&x),sizeof(my_class));
}

my_class read_from_file(int record_number){
    my_class temp;
    fstream opf("/home/rzz/file/my_file.dat", ios::in |ios::out|ios::binary);
    opf.seekg(record_number*sizeof(my_class), ios::beg);
    opf.read(reinterpret_cast< char *> (&temp),sizeof(my_class));
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    my_class zi;
    zi.fill_vec(15);
    write_to_file(zi);
    my_class zi2=read_from_file(0);
    vector<int> vec;
    vec=(zi2.get_vec());
    cout<<zi2.get_vec().size();// right answer , print 500 correctly
    cout<<"first element of vector ( should be 15 ) : "<<vec.at(0);//print 0 here , that is wrong

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Writing out a bit image of something does not generally give you
data that you can reread; the fact that you need
a `reinterpret_cast` to do so should warn you that you're on
very thin ice.  You need to define the format of the file you
want to write, or use an existing format (XDR or Google's
protocol buffers, if you want binary, XDR is a lot simpler to
implement, at least if you restrict portability to machines with
a 32 bit 2's complement integral type and IEEE floating point);
then format your data to it, in a `char` buffer, and then write
that.

EDIT:

Since I've been asked for an example:

To keep it simple, I'll format to a buffer; typically, I'd write
an oxdrstream class, and format directly to the output stream,
but this involves more complicated error handling.  I'll also
assume a 32 bit 2's complement integral type.  This is *not*
guaranteed, and there are systems where it isn't the case, but
they are fairly rare.  (Here, I use `uint32_t` and `int32_t` to
ensure that the code won't compile on systems which don't
support it.)

```
void
insertUInt( std::vector<char>& dest, uint32_t value )
{
    dest.push_back( (value >> 24) & 0xFF );
    dest.push_back( (value >> 16) & 0xFF );
    dest.push_back( (value >>  8) & 0xFF );
    dest.push_back( (value      ) & 0xFF );
}

void
insertInt( std::vector<char>& dest, int32_t value )
{
    return InsertUInt( dest, static_cast<uint32_t>(value) );
}

void
insertIntArray( std::vector<char>& dest, std::vector<int> const& value )
{
    assert( value.size() <= std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() );
    insertUInt( value.size() );
    for ( int i: value ) {
        insertInt( dest, i );
    }
}
```

(This code more or less supposes that `int32_t` is the same as
`int`.  Otherwise, you need some additional bounds checking on
each of the int values.)

Comment: can you explain more ? or give me some example please ?

Comment: thanks again , but it's a little difficult for me to understand , can you please give me a reference web site or tutorial to study and learn about it ?

Comment: I don't know of any web site handling the theme serialization globally.  I learned what was needed the hard way, before there was an internet.  (Back in the days of C, `fwrite` does take a `void*`; no explicit cast was necessary, and we dumped bit images.  And found that we couldn't read them when we upgraded the compiler, or changed the compiler options.)  As for the code itself, what don't you understand about it?  A precise question on that would certainly elicit an answer.

Comment: oh , before internet creates !!!  don't  understand this line :  (value >> 24) & 0xFF ( can you send answer to my email ? if you want me@trunk.ir )

Comment: That's the shift operator, and bitwise and for masking.  What I've just said will be sufficient _if_ you understand the internal representation of integers.  If you don't (and it's possible to do a lot of good programming without understanding them), and explication would require more space than I have here, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation looks OK for a start.